# Can I access the database of an existing application in a new application in my android phone?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, recovery

I have an android app with a database. There was one option to export the data in the app to excel files. But now there is an error in export function. So I am not able to get the data. Is there any way to recover the data from the database with out rooting the device? Can I access the data in another app?

Comment: **1** Fix it. **2** No. **3** No.

Answer (score 0):

Fir security reasons there is no possibility to access a foreign database. The only possibility to access da data of an other app is the ContentProvider of an app. 
If the app you want to access does not provide the possibility to access it from external via a ContentProvider, there is no legal possibility.

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility might be the shared user id and sign both apps with the same key.

See this documentation for more details on the topic: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid